# Mock network requests and validate sent request

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking

I want a way to mock a network request and be able to check/validate what the mock API received. Most mock frameworks only allow you to validate the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that `sinon` && [sinon.spy()](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.2.3/spies/) is exactly what you need after you have either [stubbed](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.2.3/stubs/) the function doing this API call or mocked (with `nock` library) the API call itself.

After you called a function being spied you can use `spy.calledWith(arg1, arg2, ...);` to check with which parameters this function was called with. You also have other useful tools like how many times it was called, or when etc...

Comment: I decided to use `sinon` and `moxios` (since I'm using `axios`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use nock to mock the API, It works like this.

```
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const nock = require('nock');
describe('Get User tests', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    nock('https://api.github.com')
      .get('/users/octocat')
      .reply(200, response);
  });

  it('Get a user by username', () => {

  });
});
```

Here is the link for more detail https://scotch.io/tutorials/nodejs-tests-mocking-http-requests#toc-testing-the-right-way

Comment: This seems good except it relies on using the `chai` testing framework. I want the solution to be framework agnostic.